# Anyone know the IE7 setting or update/patch that prevents IE from not loading a page because jquery error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

This is probably a hard question to answer, but in reference to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12292649/985284) does anyone know what update or setting fixes/prevents Internet Explorer from trowing an error and not loading a page when *javascript* (more precisely the JQuery DateTime Picker) is executed before IE loads the entire page?

Without repeating a lot of my linked question, I have a website that IE6, IE7 (without updates) and supposedly some IE8 browsers stop rendering the page and show this error

> Internet Explorer cannot open the Internet site XXX. Operation aborted

The script error that is responsible is this:

> Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)

I created a new *Windows XP* virtual machine and upgraded to IE7 (without installing updates) because I was unable to reproduce the error on my test system's IE7. And this new IE7 VM received the error. However upon shutting down, the VM installed updates and on the next reboot I could not reproduce the error. So I know for sure that a brand new installation of IE7 receives this error, and a fairly basic [basic in the sense that the system did not need to reboot again and install more updates,] update prevents it.

I also think that their may be settings that will cause/prevent this error too. I have reliable reports that some systems running IE8 encounter this issue too. However I have not been able to produce it.

So my question is, does anyone know what update(s) and/or Internet Explorer settings will suppress/prevent this issue? I know **why** this happens, however I am interested in what will fix/prevent IE from acting as it did.

Comment: well the error is when an element is appended to an element before it is fully rendered. Is there something on the page that is running an append()?

Comment: I do not know if this can help you, but my research for KB927917 problem gave next result: this problem can occur basically when browser try to interpret not fully correct HTML markup. It's a _"Incorrect nesting of elements"_, _"Ampersands (&'s) in URLs"_, _"Writing HTML in a SCRIPT Element"_ and other. Many people who are experiencing this problem uses the "validator W3C" to correct the problem. Also read next article about: http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#script

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that the comment statement for html was not closed. so I just closed it and problem fixed best of luck