# My site fails to show results in ie8 HTML Parsing Error KB927917

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, jscript

The site loads fine in other browsers and IE versions but in IE8 i get this problem.

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Thu, 15 May 2014 11:48:37 UTC

Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: http://jobuzu.co.uk/?q=sales+assistant&l=

Any idea how i can resolve this issue?

Also this happens on other computers with ie8....

```
function B(a) {
    return document.getElementById(a)
}

function cf(a) {
    var b = new Date;
    b.setYear(b.getFullYear() + 1);
    Ka("openSections", a, b)
}

function Ga(a) {
    var b = String(document.cookie),
        c = b.indexOf(a + "=");
    if (c == -1) {
        return "";
    }
    var d = b.indexOf(";", c);
    return b.substring(c + a.length + 1, d == -1 ? b.length : d)
}

function Ja(a) {
    return unescape(Ga(a))
}

function Ka(a, b, c) {
    document.cookie = a + "=" + escape(b) + "; path=/" + (c ? "; expires=" + c.toGMTString() : "")
}

function La(a, b) {
    document.cookie = a + "=;expires=" + (new Date(0)).toGMTString() + ";path=/" + (b ? ";domain=" + b : "")
};

function ya(a,b) {
    if (a) {
        return RegExp("(^|\\s)" + b + "(\\s|$)").test(a.className)
    }
}

function xa(a,b) {
    if (a && !ya(a,b)) {
        a.className ? a.className += " " + b : a.className = b
    }
}

window.showAllRefinements = function(a) {
  xa(B(a),"showAll")
}

window.toggleRefineBy = function(a) {
    if (ya(B(a),"rbOpen")) {
        var b = B(a);
        if (b) {
            b.className="rbSection";
        }
    } else if (b = B(a)) {
        b.className="rbSection rbOpen";
    }
    b = Ja("openSections");
    b.match(":" + a + "(:|$)") == m ? b += ":" + a : b = b.replace(":"+a,"");
    cf(b)
};

window.delSearchCookie = function(a, b) {
    a || (a = "RQ");
    $.removeCookie('csrf_token');
    /*
    La(a, b);
    */
    var c = B("recentsearches");
    c && c.parentNode.removeChild(c)
}
```

jquery.cookie.js:

```
/*!
 * jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.3.1
 * https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Klaus Hartl
 * Released under the MIT license
 */
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        // Browser globals.
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {

    var pluses = /\+/g;

    function raw(s) {
        return s;
    }

    function decoded(s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
    }

    function converted(s) {
        if (s.indexOf('"') === 0) {
            // This is a quoted cookie as according to RFC2068, unescape
            s = s.slice(1, -1).replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
        }
        try {
            return config.json ? JSON.parse(s) : s;
        } catch(er) {}
    }

    var config = $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

        // write
        if (value !== undefined) {
            options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, options);

            if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
                t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
            }

            value = config.json ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value);

            return (document.cookie = [
                config.raw ? key : encodeURIComponent(key),
                '=',
                config.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
                options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
                options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
                options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
                options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
            ].join(''));
        }

        // read
        var decode = config.raw ? raw : decoded;
        var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
        var result = key ? undefined : {};
        for (var i = 0, l = cookies.length; i < l; i++) {
            var parts = cookies[i].split('=');
            var name = decode(parts.shift());
            var cookie = decode(parts.join('='));

            if (key && key === name) {
                result = converted(cookie);
                break;
            }

            if (!key) {
                result[name] = converted(cookie);
            }
        }

        return result;
    };

    config.defaults = {};

    $.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
        if ($.cookie(key) !== undefined) {
            // Must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
            $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, { expires: -1 }));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

}));
```

Comment: Could you post your code, in particular your JavaScript? Perhaps the issue is similar to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905476/html-parsing-error-in-ie8kb927917

Comment: Here is the main javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code in a `window.onload`, like so:

```
window.onload = function() {

    //your code here

}
```

Alternatively, if you're using jQuery, you could try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //your code here

}
```